# YUI DataTable Loading...but no data retrieved

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, xmlhttprequest, yui

I have a YUI datatable bound to a YUI datasource that needs to be auto-refreshed after a couple of seconds and also manually through a button. While I am able to read the data through a local datasource (datasource declared in the same page) I am not able to read it remotely. The grid remains "Data Loading..." even though the requests to the target page (yui_data.cfm) are being made at the set interval. The source code is the following:

Source code of yui_data.cfm (for testing) is the following:

```
{ "records": [ {"id": 31, "name":"4fruit", "price":8323, "number":231}   ] }
```

Source code of the page requesting the data:

```
myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource("yui_data.cfm?");
myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource.TYPE_JSON;
myDataSource.responseSchema = {
    resultsList: "records",
        fields: [
           {key:"id", parser:"number"},
           {key:"name"},
           {key:"price",parser:"number"},
           {key:"number",parser:"number"}
        ]
};

myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("dynamicdata", myColumnDefs, myDataSource);

myCallBack = {
   success: myDataTable.onDataReturnSetRows,
   failure: function() {
   },
   scope: myDataTable,
   argument: myDataTable.getState()
}
myDataSource.setInterval(5000, null, myCallBack);
```

The above example only works when the line 
    myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource("yui_data.cfm?");
is changed to:
    myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource(YAHOO.data.sample); // as an example!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by preceding the previous JSON output with a ResultSet and Result and then modifying the response schema resultList to read from that path.